I'm getting a gradle project sync error in my android studio
My Gradle project is not able to sync because of which i am unable to use basic functionalities like editing and debugging.
This is the error that is shown:
record(9).attributeId(9) != backref attributeId(117964809)
Studio Build:
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1 Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024 Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. Windows 11.0 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 2048M Cores: 16 Registry: ide.experimental.ui=true Non-Bundled Plugins: com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.11.0) com.brandiico.jetbrains-nightfall-theme (2.0.1)
Version of Gradle Plugin: 8.4.1
Version of Gradle: 8.6
I've even tried reinstalling the application but still nothing is working out for this error.

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.
